# Save class properties in a list

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a class property called `Instructions` that I use to save my instructions data. I then save my `Instruction` class with the property to a list called `_instructionList`. Is this the best way to save my data which I can retrieve later or should I rather use another data structure like `Tuple`, `ArrayList` etc?

```
internal class Instructions
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public double LengthInMeters { get; set; }
}
```

Put the data coming from `ArrayList` to the class property and save the class with his properties in the list.

```
public void SaveInstructions(ArrayList value)
{
    _instructionList.Add(new Instructions {
         StreetName = (string)value[0],
         Latitude = (double)value[1],
         Longitude = (double)value[2],
         Kind = (string)value[3],
         LengthInMeters = (double)value[4] 
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an ArrayList at all? Use a strongly typed data-structure at *all times*, not just when "saving" your data for later.

Comment: It is possible to serialize (save) a class to XML. If you're saving your `ArrayList` to a file then better use XML approach. It's just a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I save the data coming from the API to an ArrayList and then pass the ArrayList to my SaveInstructions() method. I past the method as an ArrayList because i didn't want to have multiple parameters on my SaveInstructions() method.

Comment: You can save it to a nosql solution if you are looking to persist the data. I'd recommend dealing with an object type of List<Instructions> instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` is mostly used for compatibility with .NET 1.1. There's no reason to use it in new development.

Your question indicates that you're looking for a structure to contain the data for an instance of `Instructions` so that you can pass it to a method that will 1) create an instance of `Instructions` and 2) add it to a list.

But the structure you're looking for already exists - it's your `Instructions` class. Your method might as well look like this:

```
public void SaveInstructions(Instructions saved)
{
    _instructionList.Add(saved);
}
```

That would be my first choice - create the instance separately and just call the method to add it to the class. That way `SaveInstructions` has a simpler purpose - to add to the list.

If you did want to pass the parameters (as in your question) then you might do this:

```
public void SaveInstructions(string streetName, double latitude,
    double longitude, string kind, string lengthInMeters)
```

But that gets a little messy because the method has so many parameters. The first option is better because it doesn't require the method to "know" what all the properties of `Instructions` are.